# what does information_schema with report to below query mean?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Query: What does the below query mean and where is stored on snowflake? I don't see a table called a "table" in my snowflake but I am getting results (select * from **table**(information_schema.task_history...)

select * from table(information_schema.task_history( scheduled_time_range_start=>dateadd('day',-1,current_timestamp())))

Is this like a nested table?

Answer (score 1):

The information_schema.task_history is a table function, which means it returns a result set. TABLE keyword is used to process the result set like a table.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-table.html